# Backup Server Raid Type

Tags: backup, raid

I would need assistance in order to choose RAID 5 or RAID 10 or any other type. Server is Dell PERC H730, with  RAID levels 0, 1, 5, 6 & RAID spans 10, 50, 60.
Disks:8 * 10 TB SATA 6 Gb/s
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To only store backups, you should use a RAID type which maximize available space without compromising data safety or array reliability.

In short, I would use a **RAID6** array.

Pay attention that, if the array is performance sensitive (ie: it is not used for backups only), then RAID10 can be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the RAID level is a trade-off between reliability, performance and cost.

reliability: RAID 10 > RAID 60 > RAID 50 > RAID 6 > RAID 5

performance: RAID 10 > RAID 50 > RAID 60 > RAID 5 > RAID 6 (depending on workload)

cost: RAID 10 > RAID 60 > RAID 50 > RAID 6 > RAID 5

RAID 5 and especially RAID 6 suffer from random, small writes unless generously cached. A backup workload is likely to use large sequential reads and writes which should be fine with any of them. Given the number of disks I'd also use RAID 6 as @shodanshok suggested.